# Angular form group not returning on submit

Tags: angular

Looking at an odd problem here.  My angular form group isn't returning anything when the submit button is clicked.  It's also not logging to the console when clicked as well.  The form itself is almost identical to another I have that works just fine.

I've tried removing some parts of the html component to see if it was causing an issue (the dropdown as its calling a different object to populate the select field).  I've also attempted to print the form value and form status onto the page but it doesn't update and only returns [object Object] and remains in an invalid state.

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this.  Have I missed something somewhere?

create-locations.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Clients } from '../../../../_models/clients';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Locations } from '../../../../_models/locations';
import { LocationService } from '../../../../_services/location.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-locations',
  templateUrl: './create-locations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-locations.component.scss']
})
export class CreateLocationsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  client: Clients[];
  locations: Locations;
  createLocForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private locationService: LocationService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.client = data['clients'].result;
    });
    this.createLocationForm();
  }

  createLocationForm() {
    this.createLocForm = this.fb.group({
      LocationName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ContactFirstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      ContactLastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ContactPhone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      StreetAddress: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      City: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      State: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      PostalCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      AssociatedClient: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ValidFrom: new FormControl(),
      ValidTo: new FormControl(),
      ClientId: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  createLocation() {
    if (this.createLocForm.valid) {
      this.locations = Object.assign({}, this.createLocForm.value);
      console.log(this.createLocForm.value);
      this.locationService.CreateLocations(this.locations).subscribe(() => {
        this.alertify.success('Registration created successfully');
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
    }
  }

  cancel() {
    this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
    console.log('cancelled');
  }
}
```

create-location.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-user">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Create New Location</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="createLocForm"
          (ngSubmit)="createLocation()"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Location Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('LocationName').errors && createLocForm.get('LocationName').touched}"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="LocationName"
                placeholder="Complete Security Ltd."/>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter the location name</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contact First Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('ContactFirstName').errors && createLocForm.get('ContactFirstName').touched}"
                  formControlName="ContactFirstName"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="John"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a contact first name</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pl-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Contact Last Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('ContactFirstName').errors && createLocForm.get('ContactFirstName').touched}"
                  formControlName="ContactFirstName"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Smith"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a contact last name</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('ContactPhone').errors && createLocForm.get('ContactPhone').touched}"
                  formControlName="ContactPhone"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="604-929-3929"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a phone number</div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 pr-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Street Address</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('StreetAddress').errors && createLocForm.get('StreetAddress').touched}"
                    formControlName="StreetAddress"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="123 Main St"
                  />
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a street address</div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('City').errors && createLocForm.get('City').touched}"
                  formControlName="City"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="North Vanouver"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a city</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('State').errors && createLocForm.get('State').touched}"
                  formControlName="State"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="BC"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a state</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Country</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('Country').errors && createLocForm.get('Country').touched}"
                  formControlName="Country"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Canada"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a country</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 pl-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Postal Code</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': createLocForm.get('PostalCode').errors && createLocForm.get('PostalCode').touched}"
                  formControlName="PostalCode"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="V7H 1S6"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a postal code</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Client</label>
                <select id="ClientId"
                class="form-control" 
                formControlName="ClientId">
              <option *ngFor="let client of client" [value]="client.id">
                    {{client.organizationName + " | " + client.username}}
                  </option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a client</div>
              </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Start Date</label>
                <input
                  formControlName="ValidFrom"
                  type="date"
                  class="form-control"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input
                  formControlName="ValidTo"
                  type="date"
                  class="form-control"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
              >
              <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
            </button>
            <button
              type="reset"
              class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
              (click)="cancel()"
              >
              <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Form Value: {{createLocForm.value}} | json</p>
<p>Form Status: {{createLocForm.status}} | json</p>
```

Comment: can you provide stackbliz link? Also check your console for any error

Comment: @Sapper6fd I think the issue is resolved? I suggest you to just print the values of form without any condition on submit button. Then you will have a clear view on whats going wrong? Sometimes you don't add the required fields and it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Hey Ali. Yes, the issue was resolved. Up and running now.  The issue boiled down to a duplicate data binding that I over looked multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button (Click)="createLocation()"
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
          >
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
        </button>
```

Call the createLocation() function inside the submit button.

Comment: I've tried this as well, same result.  Nothing is posted and I'm still not able to even get a console log showing what is posted or the form field values printed to the page using:

Form Value: {{createLocForm.value}} | json

Comment: try `(click)` instead of `(onClick)`

Comment: and try `<p>Form Value: {{createLocForm.value | json}}</p>
` instead of `<p>Form Value: {{createLocForm.value}} | json</p>`

Comment: Click made not difference but after making the adjustment to the createLocForm.value recommended by Kushal, the form values are not being displayed (thanks for that).  It looks like the form is not coming out of an invalid sttate

Comment: Got the form to a valid state (Two entries in the form for FirstName and AssociatedClient should not have been present, removed now).  The form now validates properly.  Ramesh, moving the click event to the submit button works correctly now.  Thanks for your input on this. The strange thing though is I have a near identical form other than the binding variables, that works without the click event in the button filed.  (I copied that form over to save some time).

Answer (score 1):

I found some of the issues. Here is my solution and I hope this will help you:

> For your TS Component

```
createLocation() {
    if (this.createLocForm.valid) {
      this.locations = Object.assign({}, this.createLocForm.value);
      // console.log(this.createLocForm.value);
      this.locationService.CreateLocations()
          .subscribe(data => {
             this.createLocForm.setValue(data);
             console.log(this.createLocForm.value); 
             this.alertify.success('Registration created successfully');
          }, error => {
             this.alertify.error(error);
          });
    }
  }
```

Explanation:

- When you put the **console.log(this.createLocForm.value)** before the subscribe, you will receive **createLocForm.value** as undefined because in the initial, the **createLocForm** have no data so it is undefined. When you put it after subcribe, the **"data" property** as you see above in my example will contain the object. This object contains the values from the user input. **"createLocForm.value"** will receive the values of the from the **"data" property**.
- I don't think you have to pass the **"location" property** to the **"CreateLocations" method** in your service. Because when I looked at your HTML Template, I did not see you use **"location" property** to save data. But I may wrong so corrections are all welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to change the following line by removing the brakets?

```
ContactFirstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
```

Comment: I totally missed those brackets.  Removed, thanks for pointing that out.